# Django session is never authenticated even when user is logged in

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST framework with Django for backend, React for front end. I'm trying to make a GET request from my front-end to the get_user endpoint. However, even when I called login_user and confirmed that user_is_authenticated = true with that function when I call the get_user endpoint it always return false and I get an AnonymousUser. In my front end axios call I set withCredentials to true. I've also confirmed that a session_id is being created under the storage section in chrome dev tools

front end call to get_user endpoint

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      axios
        .get(url, {
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then((res) => {});
    })();
  }, [location]);
```

views.py file

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import serializers, status, permissions, status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from users.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@api_view(['GET'])
def get_user(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


@api_view(['POST'])
def register_user(request):
    match_username = User.objects.all().filter(
        username=request.data['username'])
    match_email = User.objects.all().filter(email=request.data['email'])

    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid() and not match_username and not match_email:
        user = User.objects.create(username=serializer.data['username'], password=make_password(
            serializer.data['password']), email=serializer.data['email'])
        user.save()
        send_register_email(
            serializer.data['username'], serializer.data['email'])
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, data=UserSerializer(user).data)
    else:
        if match_username:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Username already exists')
        elif match_email:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Email already exists')
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data="Invalid email")


@api_view(['POST'])
def login_user(request):
    username = User.objects.all().filter(username=request.data['username'])

    if not username:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Username not found')

    user = authenticate(
        username=request.data['username'], password=request.data['password'])

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=UserSerializer(user).data)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data='Incorrect password')
```

settings.py (relevant parts)

```
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'users',
    'settings',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}


PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher",
    "django.contrib.auth.hashers.ScryptPasswordHasher",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'users.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'users.wsgi.application'

# CORS

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

By default you need to add `authentication_classes` to views

[image]